# reprompting after invalid input

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

There was no problem until I tried to make an input go through validity check and if invalid ask again for input
i'm counting on you for ideas thanks in advance :)

```
a=0
def reinp(a,b):
    while True:
        if a in [1,2,3,4,5,6]: #checking for valid input
            return int(a)
            break
        a=input(b)
    else:
        return print("error")
```

tried, not working either

```
def reinp(a,b):
    for c in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
        if int(c)==int(a):
            return int(a)
            break
        else:
            a=input(b)
```

`a=reinp(a,'Test: ')`

This one is the first to make a problem

```
def reinp2(a,b): #trying to check if it's a number and can be turned to float if not ask again
    while check(a):
        a=input(b)
    return float(a)
def check(a):
    try:
        float(a)
        return False
    except ValueError:
        return True
```

Right now the problem is after the check it never breaks free from any while loop
i tried in place of `while True:if...break`,
`while correct:
if... correct=False`
didn't work
and it just asks again and again even a condition is met...
there is no raw_input in python 3.2 so i can't use that either
`reinp2()` is there so if there a solution found for `reinp()` the same could apply for `reinp2()` as well a and b are just variables `ans[n]=reinp2(ans[n],"Input n: ")` the same with `reinp()` just for another type of variable (one that can be float as well)

The code as it is now show no syntax errors

P.S. i'm using Python 3.2

Comment: "please ignore the last 2 line".  It's much, much better if you delete the lines so we don't have to figure out what you're talking about.  Just **Edit** the question and remove the stuff we're supposed to ignore.

Comment: sorry i just didn't want ppl to start asking what's that complicated stuff for...instead i got ppl asking to remove the note :D

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the exact problem you're having.  All we have is a bunch of code, where you say something's not working right.  What input(s) did you use, what is the error message you get, what exactly is the issue?

Comment: what do you mean what inputs? x=input() i think that's the only way in python 3.2 and there's no error msg since the script continues to loop and i edited for more info on the problem :) thanks

Comment: @Simeon: What does "ppl" mean?  And why include something that we're supposed to ignore?  Why not help us ignore it by deleting it?

Comment: i can't delete it cause i need to find+replace half of the code ppl=people i already removed the comment as you can see so anow you can read it without stopping to ignore something and give some suggestions :)

Comment: "What inputs" means what do you type in when the program asks you for input.  Your 'reinp' function as posted doesn't even compile - you can't have the "a=input(b)" indented like it is there - the syntax is invalid.

Comment: After Syntax check no errors are found (how do you think it should be?)and i need it whatever i type to undertake appropriate actions but it doesn't

Comment: @Simeon: (1) Please actually spell English words.  "ppl" doesn't mean anything (I'm a native English speaker, and pretty fluent).  (2) Please **update** the question to include all of your points from all of your comments so that there's just **one** question.  We can't interpret all the various comments -- it's just too hard to put them all together.  Also, it helps if you can post the **smallest** code that has the problem, not **all** the code.

Comment: sorry i'll try to write the whole words if there is something wrong with what you read it's not my fault from now on. I will reduce the question (again) and see if it works on local machine first) also i tried to add anything that looks relevant to the main question, did i miss something?

Comment: @Simeon: "it's not my fault"?  Why not?

Comment: @Simeon: If the problem is with `reinp2()` and `check()` why does the question show `reinp()`?  If the problem is with `reinp2()` could you show the line of code that calls `reinp2()`?  What is `a` and what is `b`?

Comment: @S.Lott `reinp2()` is there so if there a solution found for `reinp()` the same could apply for `reinp2()` as well a and b are just variables 'ans[n]=reinp2(ans[n],"Input n: ")' the same with 'reinp()` just for another type of variable (one that can be float as well) i could work something out for the second loop if i get something on the first one it's just that i'm out of ideas

Comment: @Simeon: Please **update** the question to include all of your points from all of your comments so that there's just one question.

Comment: @Simeon:  You can remove the stuff about raw_input.  Completely my fault (I only use python 2.7)

Comment: @Gerrat No problem still if you have Any idea how to do it and make it work with `input()` i'll embrace it with all my heart :) thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT:  Deleted original answer, since no longer relevant with fixed formatting on question]**

The problem with `reinp` is that `a` will be a string, and you're checking it against integers.
...so change:

```
    if a in [1,2,3,4,5,6]: #checking for valid input
```

to:

```
    if a in ['1','2','3','4','5','6']: #checking for valid input
```

If you still have a problem with `reinp2`, perhaps you can show some code that demonstrates the issue.  It looks fine to me.

Comment: the else is for the while statement(i guess i have indented it wrong but this works as well) and i'm trying to reprompt afte invalid input ([] for lists in 3.2), as the initial a is 0 i place the a=input(b) just to check if the loop works on initial data i have i

Comment: @Simeon.  In Python, indenting is significant.  It *isn't* for the while statement, since it isn't indented at that level.  If you're using tabs in your programs (which you shouldn't), you may need to fix up how things look when you post here, because what you've posted here is just plain invalid.  ...and it's hard to help you when we can't even run your program.

Comment: sorry, i know, it's my first post, please cut me some slack i checked it's ok in IDLE but something must've gotten wrong after the paste  and thanks for trying anyway :)

Comment: i can't get to `reinp2()` because the first one isn't working right it's still an infinite loop from which i can't break or terminate in a way different than Ctrl+C

Comment: @ Gerrat Thank you So much (still i don't understand why it didn't work, tried in range(1,6) same result as the other thing) i'm getting some other errors but i'll figure them out some time in the future :) and again Thank you very much for the help :) i can now calculate the math-problems-i-couldn't-resolve-by-myself-but-for-which-i-could-write-a-faulty-script-to-calculate-for-me :D

Answer (score 1):

P.S. It's complete i just wanted all of you who helped to know it's running without is any glitches i even customized it so it could receive initial data :) if someone need a permutation solver you know where to find it :)

If someone wants the script:

```
from math import *
ans=['n','k','choice',0,0,0,0,0]
n,k=0,1
a=['''1 For Permutations P (from n) = n
2 For Variations V (k emelments from n-th class) = n!/(n-k)!
3 For Combinations C (k emelments from n-th class) = n!/(k!(n-k)!) = ( n )
4 Use last answer.                                                                  ( k )
5 Second Memory
6 Clear memory

Your choice is : ''',
'''+ to add
- to substract
* to multiply
/ to divide
You will undertake?: ''',
"The answer is: "]
def perm():
    global ans
    ans[n]=reinp2(ans[n],"Input n: ")
    if ans[5]==0:
        ans[3]=factorial(ans[n])
        ans[6]=ans[3]
        return print(a[2], ans[6])
    else:
        ans[4]=factorial(ans[n])
        ans[6]=ops(ans[3],ans[4],ans[5])
        return print(a[2], ans[6])
    ans[n]=''
    ans[k]=''
def var():
    global ans
    ans[n]=reinp2(ans[n],"Input n: ")
    ans[k]=reinp2(ans[k],"Input k: ")
    if ans[5]==0:
        ans[3]=factorial(ans[n])/(factorial(ans[n]-ans[k]))
        ans[6]=ans[3]
        return print(a[2], ans[6])
    else:
        ans[4]=factorial(ans[n])/(factorial(ans[n]-ans[k]))
        ans[6]=ops(ans[3],ans[4],ans[5])
        return print(a[2], ans[6])
    ans[n]=''
    ans[k]=''
def comb():
    global ans
    ans[n]=reinp2(ans[n],"Input n: ")
    ans[k]=reinp2(ans[k],"Input k: ")
    if ans[5]==0:
        ans[3]=factorial(ans[n])/((factorial(ans[n]-ans[k]))*(factorial(ans[k])))
        ans[6]=ans[3]
        return print(a[2], ans[6])
    else:
        ans[4]=factorial(ans[n])/((factorial(ans[n]-ans[k]))*(factorial(ans[k])))
        ans[6]=ops(ans[3],ans[4],ans[5])
        return print(a[2], ans[6])
    ans[n]=''
    ans[k]=''
def ent():
    global ans,a
    ans[2]=reinp(ans[2],a[0])
    if ans[2]==5:
        if ans[3]!=0:
            ans[7]=ans[3]
        print(ans[7])
        ent()
    if ans[2]==6:
        clear()
        print("Done!")
        ent()
    if ans[3]==0 and ans[2]==4:
        print('The memory is empty...')
        ent()
    elif ans[3]!=0 and ans[2]==4:
        ans[3]=ans[3]
        ans[5]=reinp1(ans[5],a[1])
        if ans[5] == '+' :
            ans[5]='add'
            print("Adding")
        elif ans[5] == '-' :
            ans[5]='sub'
            print("Substracting")
        elif ans[5] == '*' :
            ans[5]='mul'
            print("Multiplication")
        elif ans[5] == '/' :
            ans[5]='div'
            print("Dividing")
        ans[2]='choice'
        ent()
    if ans[2]==1:
        perm()
    elif ans[2]==2:
        var()
    elif ans[2]==3:
        comb()
    clear1()
    ent()
def ops(a,b,c):
    if c=='add':
        return a+b
    if c=='sub':
        return a-b
    if c=='mul':
        return a*b
    if c=='div':
        return a/b
def reinp(a,b):
    while True:
        a=input(b)
        if str(a) in ['1','2','3','4','5','6']:
            return int(a)
            break    
        else:
            print('There was an error please try again:')
def reinp1(a,b):
    while True:
        a=input(b)
        if a in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
            return a
            break
def reinp2(a,b):
    while check2(a):
        a=input(b)
    return float(a)
def check2(a):
    try:
        float(a)
        return False
    except ValueError:
        return True
def clear():
    ans[0]='n'
    ans[1]='k'
    ans[2]='choice'
    ans[3]=0
    ans[4]=0
    ans[5]=0
    ans[7]=ans[6]
    ans[6]=0
def clear1():
    ans[0]='n'
    ans[1]='k'
    ans[2]='choice'
ent()
```